# How to Unmarshall Viper config value to struct containing array of string properly?

Tags: go, viper-go, go-cobra

I noticed that this is perhaps a bug when viper tries to unmarshall to struct. To explain it better, consider this:

**I have a cli command like below**

`dd-cli submit-bug --name "Bug 1" --tag reason1 --tag reason2`

Here is my command line source code

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

// SubmitBugOpts is a set of flags being exposed by this Deploy command
type SubmitBugOpts struct {
    Name string `mapstructure:"bug-name"`

    ReasonTags []string `mapstructure:"tags"`
}

var (
    submitBugOpts = SubmitBugOpts{}
)

func submitBugRun(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    fmt.Printf("Bug Name is %+v\n", submitBugOpts.Name)
    fmt.Printf("List of tags is %+v\n", submitBugOpts.ReasonTags)
    fmt.Printf("Length of tags is %d\n", len(submitBugOpts.ReasonTags))
    for index, el := range submitBugOpts.ReasonTags {
        fmt.Printf("tag[%d] = %s\n", index, el)
    }
}

var submitBugCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "submit-bug",
    Short: "Deploy/Install a helm chart to Kubernetes cluster",
    Run:   submitBugRun,
    PreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        pFlags := cmd.PersistentFlags()
        viper.BindPFlag("bug-name", pFlags.Lookup("name"))
        viper.BindPFlag("tags", pFlags.Lookup("tag"))

        fmt.Printf("Viper all setting value: %+v\n", viper.AllSettings())
        fmt.Printf("Before unmarshall: %+v\n", submitBugOpts)
        viper.Unmarshal(&submitBugOpts)
        fmt.Printf("After unmarshall: %+v\n", submitBugOpts)
    },
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(submitBugCmd)

    pFlags := submitBugCmd.PersistentFlags()
    pFlags.StringVar(&submitBugOpts.Name, "name", "", "the bug name")
    pFlags.StringArrayVar(&submitBugOpts.ReasonTags, "tag", nil, "the bug's reason tag. You can define it multiple times")

    submitBugCmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("name")
    submitBugCmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("tag")
}
```

**I run this command:**

```
dd-cli submit-bug --name "Bug 1" --tag reason1 --tag reason2
```

**And the output is below**

```
Viper all setting value: map[bug-name:Bug 1 tags:[reason1,reason2]]
Before unmarshall: {Name:Bug 1 ReasonTags:[reason1 reason2]}
After unmarshall: {Name:Bug 1 ReasonTags:[[reason1 reason2]]}
Bug Name is Bug 1
List of tags is [[reason1 reason2]]
Length of tags is 2
tag[0] = [reason1
tag[1] = reason2]
```

I expect the `viper.Unmarshall()` will correctly omit the `[` for  `submitBugOpts.ReasonTags [0]` and omit the `]` for `submitBugOpts.ReasonTags[1]`. So the expected value of submitBugOpts.ReasonTags doesn't contains any `[` and `]` .

Any pointer how to fix this? I've submitted this issue on viper repo: https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/527. However I am asking on SO just in case you guys know how to handle this too.

Comment: Maybe I miss something or you unmarshaling something that is already unmarshalled? Or what is the reason to make it because values are already properly binded to struct

Comment: @ttomalak this is because the value coming from (viper) co fig file only binds to the viper instance, not to struct.  I want to decouple my app logic from viper, that is why i want to unmarshall viper values to the struct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging into codes of `github.com/spf13/{cobra,viper,pflag}`for quite a while, I finally find the problem.

When you call `pFlags.StringArrayVar(&submitBugOpts.ReasonTags, "tag", nil, ...)`, the `ReasonTags`, of course, binds to a wrapper of `pflag.stringArrayValue`. [source](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/d493c32b69b8c6f2377bf30bc4d70267ffbc0793/viper.go#L831).

And when you call `viper.Unmarshall`, viper uses `v.Get` to get the value binds to `ReasonTags` and then it calls `v.find`.

In `v.find`, after the value is found, it uses the wrapper's `ValueType()` method to determine its type, the wrapper then calls the `Type` method of the wrapped type, `pflag.stringArrayValue`, and returns `"stringArray"`. [source](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/3ebe029320b2676d667ae88da602a5f854788a8a/string_array.go#L27)

But viper only handle `"stringSlice"` as a special case, so the value gets to `default` part of type switch, which uses its `ValueString()` method - making it into a string, with `"["` and `"]"` on both side. [source](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/d493c32b69b8c6f2377bf30bc4d70267ffbc0793/viper.go#L921)

And when finally unmarshalling, as your output param, `ReasonTags` is of `[]string`, the program simply splitted the string and set it into the field.

As for solution, if you are ok with prohibitting `tag` to contain `,`, simply change `StringArrayVar` to `StringSliceVar`, but this will results in `--tag "Yet, the problem re-occurs"` into `[]string{"Yet"," the problem re-occrus"}`.

If that is critical, you'll need to ask the developers of viper to create a case for `stringArray`.